# Is it possible to insert a literal character in a TO_CHAR(datetime) format?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'd like to select some dates in the format:

```
yyyydDOY
```

where `yyyy` is the 4-digit year, `DOY` is the day of year (1-366), and `d` is a literal "d".  Here's what I tried:

```
SQL> select to_char(sysdate, 'YYYYdDDD') from dual;

TO_CHAR(
--------
20130713
```

Obviously that's all wrong.  The result I want can be found on the command line:

```
$ date +'%Yd%j'
2013d071
```

Answer (score 19):

First off, the code in the question is read as `DDDD`, which the function interprets to be `DDD` (the day of year: 071) followed by `D` (the day of week: 3).

The solution is to quote any literals with double quotation marks (`"`):

```
SQL> select to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY"d"DDD') from dual;

TO_CHAR(
--------
2013d071
```

See [*Table 3-15 Datetime Format Elements*](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/sql_elements004.htm#CDEHIFJA) for more information.

Comment: Even being duplicated, it was a good answer.